# dplyr select executes weirdly another column

Tags: r, dplyr

the object 'customer_profiling_vars' is a dataframe with just variable selected by a clustering algorithm ([RSKC](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/RSKC/index.html)) as seen in R output below the R code:

```
customer_profiling_vars
customer_profiling_vars$Variables
```

[image]

Now, I want to select only those variables to my dataset [sc_df_tr_dummified](https://bitbucket.org/ammubharatram/kaggle-housing/src/8a55963ed43844c01152e8106f6d261194ef9d4b/sc_df_tr_dummied.csv)     in the above vector of variables from the dataframe 'customer_profiling_vars' using dplyr's 'select' :

```
customer_df_interprete = sc_df_tr_dummified %>% 
select(customer_profiling_vars$Variables)
glimpse(customer_df_interprete)
```

I expect to get the variable 'SalePrice' selected.

However some other variable ('PoolArea.576') gets selected which is very weird:

[image]

Just to be sure, I tried using SalePrice directly instead of customer_profiling_vars$Variables, it gives what I intended:

[image]

What is wrong with select of dplyr? For me , it seems like it has something to do with the factor nature of 'customer_profiling_vars$Variables':

[image]

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please edit your post so that it contains code samples instead of images. And yes, this is probably due to `customer_profiling_vars$Variables` being a factor. Try converting it to a character vector first.

Comment: @MRau Im sorry, but how to convert R outputs to code samples?

Comment: copy and paste your code instead of making screen captures, it should in fact be easier. Tor format it properly either put 4 spaces in front of code or use the `{}` icon after selecting your code.

Comment: You can also check [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/22189) for tips on code formatting or [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5963610/8918309) on how to make a reproducible example

Comment: @Moody_Mudskipper Lol, that is exactly what  I did for code (if you read the question again). I asked about R-output.

Comment: Thanks @MRau , reproducible example answer really helps!

Comment: well that's not different :), copy and paste it from your console, and common usage here is to add `#` or `#>` to your output, you can also check the *`reprex`* package.

Comment: Great, thanks Moody! Will edit question by using #> and reprex.